# Wordpress and two styles

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm not a PHP coder but with some help (Adam Burkenpas's tutorial) I created my 1st Wordpress theme. It's a  static page (front page) and blog. There is a problem with the  blog page, there are two different styles one for  the blog  and one for the front page. Some classes (like body) have the same name, and when I load the blog css  by functions.php  it's getting mess on my front page (wrong fonts, wrong font's colour). I changed name of body in  blog CSS to 'blog.body'  add class in a HTML by  ", but didn't help. How to fix it ?

css code

http://jsbin.com/xaredeneru

Comment: Are you trying to achieve 2 different styles in 2 different pages (front-page and home (home is post listing page) ), right?

Comment: yes,  just like that

Comment: Well, i was going to say but people already said it. You can use `body_class` and to aim for ( front-page ) you can use `body.home .myclass {} ` and to aim for blog listing pages you can use `body.blog .myclass{}`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to specify different body class than you may take a look at https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/body_class
based on that you can check page and add specific body class for that page .
now in css you can just give style with parent dependency like :

```
body.myclass .mytext{color:#000;}
```

and for page 2 :

```
body.someotherclass .mytext{color:#000;}
```

Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

You can use combined seletors in CSS: Usually the `<body>` tag automatically gets assigned one or more unique classes by Wordpress, or also a class like `page` or `single-post`. You see these when you examine the generated page with the bowser's developer tools.

So you can for example use `body.page {...}` to define the rules for the body of pages and `body.archive {...}` for the body in archive pages.

And you can also for example use `.page .nav {...}` to only style the `.nav` class elements on *pages*. And so on...

Answer (score 0):

Like @den-pat and @johannes said...

You can use the [`body_class()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/body_class/) function and wordpress will automatically set some body classes for you, if you want know what are the classes and when they appear you can [take a look here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.6/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L570).

But the css class for front-page is `.home` and the css class for blog ( post listing page ) is `.blog`

You can replace your current body tag code

```
<body class="blog">
```

with

```
<body body_class() >
```

and use the css selectors to separate the styles

```
body.home { // aim for front-page template
 background: #ccc;
}

body.blog { // aim for blog template
 background: #666;
}
```

In case you wanna set your body classes dynamically, it's worthy to read about [`body_class`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/body_class/) filter hook.